# Display version of software reading from registry

Tags: vb.net, registry, registrykey

I need the version value of certain software, so I find this code that reads from registry:

```
Dim pRegKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine
        pRegKey = pRegKey.OpenSubKey("HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0")
        Dim val As Object = pRegKey.GetValue("Identifier")
        MsgBox("The value is:" + val)
```

Works for that value. But when I try to read from subkey "SOFTWARE" with this code:

```
 Dim pRegKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine
        pRegKey = pRegKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Installer\\UserData\\S-1-5-18\\Products\\CB4BAAC7DA509BF41AC3F3D8241731F9\\InstallProperties")
        Dim val As Object = pRegKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion")
        MsgBox("The value is: " + val)
```

I'm getting this error: "A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsApplication1.exe"

Can someone please tell me why this second code doesn't work. I'll be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: The problem is solved.